# Why is local storage set in beforeEach not persistent in actual cypress test?

Tags: cypress

The 'Add Article' button is present only if the user is logged in (we have in local storage 'user' key with a specific value)
Even if I set the 'user' key to local storage in beforeEach method, the test fails because it can not find the 'New Article' button, because apparently the user does not appear as logged in

```
beforeEach(() => {


        let res;
        cy.request({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/api/users/login",
            body: {
                "user": {
                    "email":"test@test.com",
                    "password":"test"
                }
            }
        }).then(response => {
            res = response
        })
        cy.visit("http://localhost:3000", {
            onBeforeLoad: function(win) {
                win.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res.body.user))
            }
        })
    })

    it("Add Article", () => {
        cy.contains("New Article").click()
        cy.get("input[placeholder='Article Title']").type("Article on cypress")
        cy.get("input[placeholder='What\\'s this article about?']").type("Topic is cypress")
        cy.get("[placeholder='Write your article (in markdown)']").type("Content of article")
        cy.get("input[placeholder='Enter tags']").type("Test Automation")
        cy.contains("button", "Publish Article").click()
        cy.contains("button", "Publish Article").click()
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to save the response to an alias. You may experience problems invoking `cy.visit()` inside the callback function of `cy.request()`. An alias is an alternative to external variables that works well in this situation.

```js
let res
beforeEach(() => {

  cy.request({
    ...
  }).as('res')     // save to alias here

  cy.get('@res').then(response => {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000", {
      onBeforeLoad: function(win) {
        win.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.body.user))
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using "closure" variables that are defined outside of commands is often dicey, because the commands like `cy.request()` take time to resolve.

You can try moving the visit inside the `.then()` callback, which guarantees the value is coming from the response, and don't rely on the closure variable.

```js
beforeEach(() => {

  cy.request({
    ...
  }).then(response => {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000", {
      onBeforeLoad: function(win) {
        win.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.body.user))
      }
    })
  })
```